# Number of query values and destination fields are not the same (Union)

Tags: sql, ms-access

Running into this SQL error - number of query values and destination fields are not the same (Union). Using an Access database. The programList table has just two fields in it - userID and programID. Using parameters in my cs file. Here is the complete method:

```
public void AddProgramList (string program, int userID)
{
    dbConnection.Open();

    string sqlStmt = "INSERT INTO programs (program) ";
    sqlStmt += "VALUES (@program)";
    string sqlStmt2 = "INSERT INTO programList (userID, programID) " +
                      "SELECT userID " +
                      "FROM users" +
                      "WHERE userID = @userID " +
                      "UNION " +
                      "SELECT programID " +
                      "FROM programs" +
                      "WHERE program = @program;";

    OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlStmt, dbConnection);

    OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter("@program", program);

    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@userID", userID));

    OleDbCommand dbCommand2 = new OleDbCommand(sqlStmt2, dbConnection);

    OleDbParameter param2 = new OleDbParameter("@program", program);

    dbCommand2.Parameters.Add(param2);

    dbCommand2.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@userID", userID));


    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    dbCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    dbConnection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you printed out the SQL, you would see:

```
INSERT INTO programList (userID, programID) " +
SELECT userID FROM usersWHERE userID = @userID UNION SELECT programID FROM programsWHERE program = @program;
```

The error should be pretty obvious.  You probably don't have a table called `usersWHERE`.

As I look at the problem, you are trying to insert *two* columns.  So, I think you intend:

```
INSERT INTO programList (userID, programID)
    SELECT userID, programID
    FROM users, programs
    WHERE userID = @userID AND program = @program;
```

Or, more simply:

```
INSERT INTO programList (userID, programID)
    SELECT @userID, programid
    FROM programs
    WHERE program = @program;
```

Comment: Yep, I'm a big dummy

Comment: @JohnVinson . . . Not at all.  But you should learn to print out the strings even before you ever execute the code.  After all, you want it to be correct, and verifying is the best insurance.

Comment: Hmm, fixed the spacing issue and still getting the error

Comment: So no error now, making progress. Now it just isn't adding the data.

Comment: @JohnVinson . . . I misread the variables you are using.  `VALUES` is not sufficient for this purpose.